# Google Chart not getting displayed on selection of SelectOptions value in VF Page

Tags: visualforce

Apex Controller :

```
public with sharing class AccountController {

public List<SelectOption> getListOfAccounts()
 {
   List<Account> AccountList = [select id,Name from Account] ;
   System.debug('Accounts'+AccountList.size());
   List<SelectOption> AccountOptionList = new List<SelectOption>();
   AccountOptionList .add(new SelectOption( ' ' ,'---Select---'));
   for(Account acc : AccountList )
   {
              AccountOptionList .add(new SelectOption(acc.id , acc.Name));
   }
  return AccountOptionList ;
}

public String selectedaccountId { get; set; }

public AccountController() {

}
}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select the Account" >
              <apex:OutputPanel >
                         <apex:selectList value="{!selectedaccountId}" size="1" multiselect="false"  id="theSelectList" onChange="doChange();">
                                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListOfAccounts}" />
                         </apex:selectList>
                         <script> var options = document.getElementById("{!$Component.theSelectList}"); </script>
                </apex:OutputPanel>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<html>
  <head>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
</script>
<script src="../../soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../soap/ajax/24.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   var noOfCase;
   function doChange(){
  var accId =options.value; 
   console.log('@@selectedaccountId=='+accId);
  // alert(options.value); 

  var caseQuery = sforce.connection.query(" select Id from case where AccountId= \'"+accId +"\' ");
  var case_records = caseQuery.getArray("records");
  noOfCase = +case_records.length;
  console.log('@@noOfCase =='+noOfCase);


   }

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {


var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Cases'); // must be string
data.addColumn('number', 'value');
data.addRow(['Cases',noOfCase]);

var options = {
  width: 400, height: 120,
  redFrom: 0, redTo: 33,
  yellowFrom: 34, yellowTo: 66,
  greenFrom: 67 , greenTo: 100
  minorTicks: 5 
  };

var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, options);


  }
</script>
```

On selection of Account on the VF page , a Google gauge chart needs to be displayed indicating number of cases associated with the selected account .
The chart got displayed once , post that it's not getting displayed .
I am assuming the reason to be chart not getting refreshed on selection . 
I think we cannot use rerender as well .
Any other way ?

Comment: Can u try this....onChange="doChange(); return false;

Comment: @PrabhatKumar Tried this : <apex:selectList value="{!selectedaccountId}" size="1" multiselect="false"  id="theSelectList" onChange="doChange();" return='false'> . Getting the error - Unsupported attribute return in <apex:selectList>

Comment: "doChange(); return false;" use something like this

Comment: @PrabhatKumar  Are you saying like this ? onChange="doChange();" return="false;" - This is also throwing the same error .

Comment: <apex:selectList value="{!selectedaccountId}" size="1" multiselect="false"  id="theSelectList" onChange="doChange(); return false;"> Replace you code with this.

Comment: @PrabhatKumar - Tried this . Did not throw any error and got saved . However , the chart still did not get displayed . I guess refresh issue still persists. Any other way out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34525/discussion-between-vanilla-sky-and-prabhat-kumar).